# How to make activity start at the bottom of the ScrollView?

Tags: android-activity, scroll, scrollview

I want to make a quiz application with levels. It has a long background image and as you scroll down, at the bottom I have the levels 1, 2, 3,...going up. How can I make the activity scroll at the bottom automatically when I enter the app?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ScrollView scrollview = findViewById(R.id.scrollView);     
scrollview.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         scrollview.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
    }
});
```